# At which point during the first boot are tasks in pkg_postinst_ontarget performed?

Tags: yocto, boot, bitbake

I'm designing a device which would need to perform a number of setup activities at first boot and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it. One of the tools at my disposal seems to be [fantastically incompletely documented](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-post-installation-scripts) `pkg_postinst_ontarget`.

One of the activities I need to perform depends on an SD card being successfully mounted. Would `pkg_postinst_ontarget` get executed after all fstab mounting activities have completed?

Answer (score 1):

The yocto build places the post-installation scripts in `/etc/ipk-postinsts` if you are using ipk packages. Then, those scripts are typically run by systemd on target: the `run-postinsts.service` unit runs `/usr/sbin/run-postinsts` which runs and deletes all the scripts stored in `/etc/ipk-postinsts`. Hence, the scripts are run once at the first startup but disappear after they have been executed.